# how to unpickle an nlp model

Tags: python, nlp, pickle, spacy

I have trained a spacy blank NER NLP model and I want to save it in order to use it in an application, I thought about pickling it
I managed to that using those two lines

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(nlp, open( "nlp.p", "wb" ))
```

but when I wanted to use it I couldn't load it
I tried

```
pickle_in = open('/content/nlp.p', 'rb')
pickle_clf = pickle.load(pickle_in)
```

it prints

```
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

how can I unpickle it and test it on a text

Comment: Filename in first code snippet has no path information. Are you sure that both paths refer to the same file?

Comment: @MichaelButscher yeah because i work with google colab and after generating the nlp.p and got it in the content file i copied the path from there

Comment: I would use full path in both command. Don't trust Google. It may have other file with the same name.

Comment: okey i'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think pickling should work as usual with spaCy models, but you may be better off using the built in serialization methods.

```
# save your model
nlp.to_disk("my-model") # creates a directory at this path

# load it back
nlp = spacy.load("my-model")
```